# How do I make a switch.toggle() take effect within a ForEach loop?

Tags: list, foreach, swiftui

I am trying to alternate at the background color of a List/ForEach using a @State var and toggling it on each repetition. The result is alway that the last color behind the entire List. I have set a breakpoint a Text view inside the ForEach and executing it, I see a stop once per item in the input array, then a display on the screen as expected (i.e. every second row is red and the rest are blue). Then, for some reason, we iterate through the code again, one for each item and leave the loop with the background color of all rows being blue.

The code below is a simplified version of my original problem, which iterates over a Realm Results and is expected to handle a NavigationLink rather than the Text-view and handle deleting items as well.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let array = ["olle", "kalle", "ville", "valle", "viktor"]
    @State var mySwitch = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(array, id: \.self) { name in
                Text(name)
                    .onAppear() {
                        mySwitch.toggle()
                        print("\(mySwitch)")
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(mySwitch ? Color.blue : Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It because of  `@State var mySwitch = false` variable is attached with all row of `ForEach` so whenever your mySwitch var change it will affect your all row.

So if you want to make some alternative way, you can use the index of item and check whether your number is even or not and do your stuff according to them.

Demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let array = ["olle", "kalle", "ville", "valle", "viktor"]
    @State var mySwitch = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(array.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(array[index])
                    .onAppear() {
                        mySwitch.toggle()
                        print("\(mySwitch)")
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(index.isMultiple(of: 2) ? Color.blue : Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Raja: in your code mySwitch is going turn ON and turn OFF in array.indices, I think OP want just get turned ON, then I think it would better use a if  mySwitch != true { mySwitch = true }

Comment: Thanks for that solution, Raja. Unfortunately, addressing the indata by index introduces problems with the sync between the Realm database and the ListView.